# char to integer C with struct

Tags: c, char, integer, variable-assignment

I have this problem where I have made a linked list. I am reading from a textfile and saving certain info into a char variable and when then I have this struct integer where I am trying to insert it into but it fails. The value saved in the char is for certain an integer.

```
struct..

...
char *variable;
...
reading file

temp = (theStruct*)malloc(sizeof(theStruct));
temp->structInteger = variable;
...
```

Essentially what my problem is that it won't let me put the char into the structInteger and I get this warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast. So I am wondering how do I get past this problem? Can I somehow put my char value into the integer because right now I just get some random number. I have looked around but didn't find anything that satisfied my needs.

Comment: DataType of `variable` is not `char` it is `char*`. There is a great difference between them.

Comment: Here variable is a char pointer not char type

Comment: Yes, sorry. It is supposed to say char*, but how do I copy it over?

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with `struct`. Try to get to the essential of your question before asking here.

Comment: Neither did I say so, I just tried giving more information. If you look further down in the thread you can see how people answered my question correctly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your `char * variable` is intended to be a string that represents a number:

There is `atoi()` (and `atol()`) and `strtol()` to choose between.

The `atoi()` and `atol()` just convert what they can, 
`strtol()` is more advanced and handles bad parsing better by showing you where your input stops being parsable.

Answer (score 1):

You are essentially trying to save a characgter value into integer without cast.
Use atoi to convert string to int and then try saving it.

```
temp->structInteger = atoi(variable);
```